# C# Newtonsoft deserialize JSON array

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an array using Newtonsoft so i can display files from a cloud based server in a listbox but i always end up getting this error no matter what i try:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].priv', line 4, position 15.'

Thisis an example try to deserialize:

```
[
 {
  "code": 200,
  "priv": [
     {
        "file": "file.txt",
        "ext": "txt",
        "size": "104.86"
     },
     {
        "file": "file2.exe",
        "ext": "exe",
        "size": "173.74"
     },

  ],
  "pub": [
     {
        "file": "file.txt",
        "ext": "txt",
        "size": "104.86"
     },
     {
        "file": "file2.exe",
        "ext": "exe",
        "size": "173.74"
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

I tried using a C# Class like this:

```
    public class ListJson
{
    [JsonProperty("pub")]
    public List List { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    [JsonProperty("file")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ext")]
    public string Ext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
    [JsonProperty("priv")]
public List List { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    [JsonProperty("file")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ext")]
    public string Ext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize with:

```
List<list> fetch = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<list>>(json);
```

Comment: Have you used this to validate your [JSON](http://json.parser.online.fr/) *hint* it has a syntax error

Comment: It's not my json i got it from the API of the server so nothing much i can do to that :/ i'll tell the owner of the website

Comment: you have 2 classes called `List`...?

Comment: the name List as a class is confusing

Comment: Also, there is a C# class called `List` - please refrain from confusing the name of classes that already exist.

Comment: I used list since it's used to list the files

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio - you can copy the JSON into memory using (ctrl+c) . Click on edit --> Paste Special --> Paste Json as Classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct C# class structure for your JSON is the following:

```
public class FileEntry
{
    public string file { get; set; }
    public string ext { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FileList
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public List<FileEntry> priv { get; set; }
    public List<FileEntry> pub { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing it in this way:

```
var fetch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileList[]>(json);
var fileList = fetch.First(); // here we have a single FileList object
```

As said in the other answer, creating a class called `List` doesn't automagically turn it into a collection of objects. You need to declare the types to be deserialized from an array a collection type (e.g. `List<T>`, `T[]`, etc.).

*Small tip: when in doubt, use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate strongly typed classes from a json string.*

Comment: Now i'm stuck on actually using the deserialized json :/ i really suck at this

Comment: @Zeq stuck where? Here it is a small [demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZEqKlT).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot i will try to figure it out from here also the json gets downloaded from a server so it changes depending on the files

Comment: @Zeq what part changes?

Comment: The json i use this to download the file on start `client.DownloadFile("https://www.zeroside.co/api/list/" + fetch[0].id + "/" + fetch[0].token, zerolist);`

Comment: Nvm i fugured it out

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `List` has a single `List` instance called `priv`, which despite the name: doesn't make it a list. To deserialize a JSON array (`"priv": [...]`), it needs to an array or list-like type, for example `List<T>` for some `T`. Presumably a `List<FileThing>`, if we assume that `FileThing` is actually the second type called `List` (you have 2).

Comment: My class is called list

Comment: @Zeq they're not **both** called `List` (at least: not in the same namespace)... because *that isn't legal C#*... but that isn't the point. The problem isn't the name... it is that it needs to be an array or list-like type. You could rename your `List` type(s) to `Banana`, and everything I said would remain identical.