# Cannot deserialze the current JSON array into type

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize following JSON data:

```json
{
  "bids": [
             [ "392031.00000000", "0.00254444" ],
             [ "390000.00000000", "0.52917503" ],
                ......
  ],
  "asks": [
             [ "392999.00000000", "1.00000000" ],
             [ "393000.00000000", "0.31572236" ],
             .....
  ]
}
```

I've looked into similar question such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011596/c-sharp-newtonsoft-deserialize-json-array), but I'm not getting close result and also noticed that in that question the structure of JSON is not similar.

My code for deserialization is as below

```
public class OrderBookElement
{
    // I've also tried below commented code
    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "0")]
    //public double price { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
    //public double volume { get; set; }

    List<double> values;
}
public class OrderBookResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bids")]
    List<OrderBookElement> bids { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "asks")]
    List<OrderBookElement> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Below is code that I use for deserialization

```
var ordBook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderBookResponse>(jsonResponse);
```

This gives me error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`)
> into type `RestAPI.OrderBookElement` because the type requires
> a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object
> (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) or change the deserialized type to
> an array or a type that implements a collection interface
> (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized
> from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type
> to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: I had similar error and now i looling for best resovle, now i can offer to you chanhe this: var ordBook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderBookResponse>(jsonResponse); TO:var ordBook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderBookResponse>>(jsonResponse);

Comment: Looks like a list of lists for `bids` and `asks` since you have `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ ... ], ... ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON you've shown would be represented by:

```
public class OrderBookResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public List<List<string>> Bids { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public List<List<string>> Asks { get; set; }
}
```

The `bids` and `asks` properties in the JSON are each just an array of arrays of strings.

I'd suggest deserializing to a model which matches the JSON, then convert that into a more useful model separately. It *may* be possible to apply attributes to your class to persuade Json.NET to do what you want, but I tend to think that by the time there's a significant discrepancy (not just the property names), it's worth separating the two models out, one for serialization and one for use within the rest of your code.